# Why is an example use of an "iso" parameter?

Tags: ponylang

In the [tutorial](http://tutorial.ponylang.org/capabilities/aliasing/), an `iso` variable gets aliased as `trn`:

```
fun test(a: Wombat iso) =>
  var b: Wombat tag = a // Allowed!
```

But I am wondering what is the actual use case for getting an `iso` variable, if you can't read from it?

Say, can I do something like this?

```
fun test(a: Wombat iso) =>
  var b: Wombat tag = a // Allowed!
  env.out.print(a.name())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reference capabilities](http://tutorial.ponylang.org/capabilities/reference-capabilities/) explains:

> Isolated, written iso. This is for references to isolated data
>   structures. If you have an iso variable then you know that there are
>   no other variables that can access that data. So you can change it
>   however you like and give it to another actor.

It means it's perfectly fine to read from iso reference.

You can test your example code in [Pony sandbox](http://sandbox.ponylang.org/) and see for yourself.

Comment: Indeed, once I read the tutorial further it made sense :-) (with the consume section)!